# Disabling Cache in Apache Felix

Tags: java, caching, osgi, apache-felix

i'm trying to follow the instructions in this thread (http://osdir.com/ml/dev-felix-apache/2009-05/msg00051.html) to disable file system bundle cache in felix. I couldn not find a concrete example online.

Can somebody help me with this? Is this really working?

Thanks in advance.

Klaus.

Answer (score 7):

It is not possible to disable the bundle cache, it is required by the framework. You can configure it to be cleaned each startup (org.osgi.framework.storage.clean) or you can try to use the approach referenced in your URL to create your own bundle cache. Those are your only options, other than hacking on the framework code itself. The bundle cache has changed a little bit since the info referenced by URL was written, so it is not clear if there was an impact on the approach.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Is it by any chance possible to provide Felix with my own classloader, say per bundle?

Klaus.

Comment: For added clarification, I found the following in conf/config.properties

# The following property controls whether the bundle cache is flushed
# the first time the framework is initialized. Possible values are
# "none" and "onFirstInit"; the default is "none".
org.osgi.framework.storage.clean=onFirstInit

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation : 
http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-framework/apache-felix-framework-bundle-cache.html

```
configurationProperties.setProperty(Constants.FRAMEWORK_STORAGE_CLEAN, Constants.FRAMEWORK_STORAGE_CLEAN_ONFIRSTINIT);
```