# Felix clean cache dir

Tags: osgi, apache-felix

I found this topic about Felix cache

[Disabling Cache in Apache Felix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165528/disabling-cache-in-apache-felix)

Can you give me some example how I can use below code because I can't find configurationProperties.

```
configurationProperties.setProperty(Constants.FRAMEWORK_STORAGE_CLEAN, Constants.FRAMEWORK_STORAGE_CLEAN_ONFIRSTINIT);
```

Comment: The link you post actually contains the answer to this question.

Comment: I assume that you mean org.osgi.framework.storage.clean? I cannot find it.

Comment: Scroll down here http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-framework-bundle-cache.html and also take a look at the document referenced there on how to set these properties: http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-framework/apache-felix-framework-usage-documentation.html#ApacheFelixFrameworkUsageDocumentation-configuringframework

Comment: Unfortunately I'm new to Java. Can you please show me some basic example how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use code from this page:
[How to start and use Apache Felix from code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887809/how-to-start-and-use-apache-felix-from-code)

In this code configurationProperties is names just map.

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put(Constants.FRAMEWORK_SYSTEMPACKAGES_EXTRA,
    "some.module.i.dont.know; version=1.0.0");
```

You could set your property:

```
map.setProperty(Constants.FRAMEWORK_STORAGE_CLEAN, Constants.FRAMEWORK_STORAGE_CLEAN_ONFIRSTINIT);
```